# Maven3-based installer

Tags: xml, jvm, installation, maven-3

I have 10+ repos and 20+ artifacts.

I want to create installer for these artifacts. I've used recently "maven-dependency-plugin" which did download my artifacts to /target and my custom groovy script took these artifacts and install them using scenario.

Now there are more than 20 artifacts with different versions. I don't want to change installer pom.xml each time I need to install new artifact.
Previous version look this way:

```
   <build>
                    <plugins>
                        <plugin>
                            <groupId>org.codehaus.gmaven</groupId>
                            <artifactId>gmaven-plugin</artifactId>
                            <executions>
                                <execution>
                                    <phase>install</phase>
                                    <goals>
                                        <goal>execute</goal>
                                    </goals>
                                    <configuration>
                                        <source>${pom.basedir}/src/main/script/app-installer.groovy</source>
                                    </configuration>
                                </execution>
                            </executions>
                        </plugin>
                        <plugin>
                            <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
                            <artifactId>maven-dependency-plugin</artifactId>
                            <version>2.6</version>
                            <executions>
                                <execution>
                                    <phase>process-resources</phase>
                                    <goals>
                                        <goal>copy</goal>
                                    </goals>
                                    <configuration>
                                        <artifactItems>
                                            <artifactItem>
                                                <groupId>ru.my.project</groupId>
                                                <artifactId>project-module-name</artifactId>
                                                <version>1.0</version>
                                                <type>zip</type>
                                                <outputDirectory>${project.build.outputDirectory}</outputDirectory>
                                                <destFileName>${installer.artifact.project.module.name}</destFileName>
                                            </artifactItem>
<!-- many more artifacts... -->
                                        </artifactItems>
                                    </configuration>
                                </execution>
                            </executions>
                        </plugin>
                        <plugin>
                            <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
                            <artifactId>maven-enforcer-plugin</artifactId>
                            <version>1.3.1</version>
                            <executions>
                                <execution>
                                    <id>enforce-property</id>
                                    <goals>
                                        <goal>enforce</goal>
                                    </goals>
                                    <configuration>
                                        <rules>
                                            <requireProperty>
                                                <property>url</property>
                                                <message>You must set property url and you can set property keyFile</message>
                                                <regex>.*@.*:\d+</regex>
                                                <regexMessage>The url property must look like in format cloudera:cloudera@localhost:22.</regexMessage>
                                            </requireProperty>
                                        </rules>
                                        <fail>true</fail>
                                    </configuration>
                                </execution>
                            </executions>
                        </plugin>
                    </plugins>
                </build>
```

Project grows and installer procedure becomes unmanageble.

The idea is:

1. Mark each module with installer-type in module pom.xml. This
   installe-type mark should tell installer how to handle this or that
   module.
2. Create installer-scenario module where installation
   scenarios should be placed. The scenario should look like: take
   listed artifacts from nexus, apply these specific properties and
   install to that environment.

The installer module should accept these arguments using -Dproperty

1. environment name
2. installer-scenario artifact
3. the concrete name of installer-scenario-file from artifact

The problems are:

1. How to automatically get artifact? I don't want to write custom
   code, I would like to reuse maven. Like:

   MavenUtil.getArtifactByName('group:artifact:version:package')
2. How to get pom.xml of specific artifact? The same, don't want to write code, want to reuse maven.
3. How to get pom object model? Don't want to parse pom, want to reuse maven utilities.